# How can I connect SSIS to SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have to Virtual Machines, one with Windows XP and the other with Windows Server 2008. In my XP VM I have SQL Server 2000 with a database that is my datasource. In WS 2008 I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with an SSIS package to pull data from SQL Server 2000.

My problem: I can not connect to SQL Server 2000, I can not create a connection in my SSIS package. The error says "The connection faild because of an error in initializing provider. Login file for user sa" I am using sa user for the connection and of course this user has access to the database.

Things I have done:

-Both VM do ping between each other.

-I am using Native OLE DB\ Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

-Did this configuration from this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx

I continue with the problem, I need to use Sql Server Authentication.
Please if any one has another suggestion, please help.

Regards, Anabel

Comment: Have you tried the SQL Native Client 10.0?

Comment: You might have to do it via an odbc connection. SSIS definitely didn't exist for SQL 2000 (DTS instead), so it may not work at all.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for answering, I already try the native client 10.0. I had read people who could connect, so it is possible. Please another idea?

Comment: Can you connect to database using ssms using the same credentials? First i would prove that i can connect from a remote machine. (Not just ping.) It could be firewall, instance name, port numbers...

Comment: No I can´t connect from ssms, same error, Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456), but the user and pass are ok, firewall off, what other thing it coul be? Thanks for answer.

Comment: I have been testing some commands, I did a telnet to my target machine, it says that It can not open a connection to the host on port 1433, How can I fix that? Ideas please, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had no problems to connect to SQL 2000 from SQL 2008 R2 is perfectly posible. My problem was a configuration problem between my two virtual machines. I tried to do the connection in a normal enviroment and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to all for the comments.

Anabel